# Wordpress Woocommerce change all products to out of stock

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

Hello i have a online shop using Wordpress and Woocommerce but i have the following problem. I need to change all of my 2000 products to be out of stock, i haven't selected any quantity i only need to change the status. I started doing it by hand but it will take quite a while to mark all the items. After browsing the net i saw that this can be done relatively easy in phpmyadmin, the status is stored in wp_postmeta, i myself tried fiddling with the queries of phpmyadmin but to no avail  . Can someone help me with building the query that i need to use ? I use WP 4.1.1

Comment: all your products type is simple or some products are variable and some are simple

Comment: All of my products should be simple, however if this is important can i run a query to check if there are variable products ?

Comment: All products should be simple

Comment: ok  bro i write a query in answer ... but first you MUST take a backup of your db

Comment: Of course, i have made back-up of the file system and of the database. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok bro write this query in your db

```
Update wp_postmeta Set meta_value = 'outofstock' Where meta_value = 'instock' And meta_key = '_stock_status'
```

I  restricted update query more by using `And meta_key = '_stock_status'`

Hope this will help you ... don't worry query is completely right but you must take a DB backup

Comment: Similar Question, but to upload multiple products from myphpadmin database. since i am new to queries, can you help me with one for uploading Product Title, Description, sku, Price and sale price, upsel and cross sell products, attributes and also the image.. i have to upload around 4000 products..so i am looking for a way to upload them all using Database..requesting your guidance..

Comment: No @JohnFranky ... bro this is not a safe way and it will take much more  time, so if you have admin of site details it will done easily ....

Comment: yes i have admin access to the wordpress, but i may have to purshase the plugin csv upload.. Can anything be done with code

Comment: bro 4000 products is not like 'piece of cake' if you want to add products with code or in phpmyadmin it can be done but its a waste of time. If the csv plugin is good then you'll try for it

Comment: if you want to add your products with csv then first you must take backup of your site and database