# Wordpress update post meta for Woocommerce stock

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to reset all stock in woocommerce to outofstock. Or set the stock on all products to zero. One or the other. Doesn't matter.

I have written this so far.

```
function clear_current_stock(){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE meta_value = 'instock' AND meta_key = '_stock_status'";
    // run queries
    if ($wpdb->query( $sql ) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record";
    }
}
```

And I have called the function like this. (Just to test it and make sure it's working)

```
   <?php clear_current_stock(); ?>
```

But the function isn't doing anything. Please help.

there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967216/wordpress-woocommerce-change-all-products-to-out-of-stock?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

But It hasn't helped me.

What I need for the finished piece of code. Is to click a button which calls this function. then sets all the posts of type product to zero stock. or outofstock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My process to the answer.

Firstly I went into MYSQL workbench and ran the query in workbench. This showed me that there was an error selecting the Database.

I fixed my sql query so it was working in MYSQL workbench. Then I continued with my function.

I found that in my function I wasn't declaring my variable.

I had to declare my variable first for $wpdb to work in the first place. Which as shown above was not been done.

This is the final function working 100%

```
// Clear Stock
function clear_current_stock(){ 
// Declare the $wpdb var
    global $wpdb;
// Run My SQL Query (My Query is setting the meta value for stock to zero)
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 0 WHERE meta_key = '_stock'");
// Check if there were any errors or if my query was successful.
    if ( is_wp_error( $wpdb ) ) {
         echo $wpdb->get_error_message();
    }
    else {
         echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Then you just need to call the function where ever or when ever you want to run the query. This can be done like so.

```
<?php clear_current_stock(); ?>
```